# How can I maximize the cheese flavor in my pizza?

Tags: cheese, pizza

I am using the best cheese that I can buy, but my pizzas still don't have much of a cheese flavor.  Is it something that I'm doing wrong, or has the cheese changed?

Comment: What cheese or cheese are you using on top? Are you using other toppings, or just crust, sauce, cheese?

Comment: Make sure you've enough salt, I've had melted mozz taste pretty bland to even kinda sweet, but after adding salt it tastes properly "cheesy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top your pizza with 2 cheeses: whole milk mozzerella and skim milk mozzerella. (Pizza restaurant secret)